# Left 4 Dead 2 Official Dedicated Bugging Going Black Screen

Tags: technical-issues, left-4-dead-2

```
Error! Variable "$blendframes" is multiply defined in material "particle/smoke1/smoke1_add_nearcull"!
```

*Left 4 Dead 2 Official Dedicated Bugging Going Black Screen*

As the keywords suggest, when starting a game, the game goes black. If you whip up console, there is this error. Which I know other people may get when they try to start up an Official Dedicated game. Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: *I know this is an old question, but I wanted to try to help any future Googlers who are running into this issue.*

Based on [this thread from the Steam Community forums](http://steamcommunity.com/app/550/discussions/0/540742485434427405/#p1), it appears that this error was due to an issue on Steam's side.

If you're still having this problem, (and you're sure it isn't caused by an add-on) try reverifying your local content (as shown here: [Is there a way to manually update a game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127901/is-there-a-way-to-manually-update-a-game)).