# Is there a way to manually update a game?

Tags: steam

As [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/81471/51318) describes, there is a way to disable automatic updates for a game. If I choose to disable automatic updates, how do I check for updates for the game in Steam?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you open up the game properties (right click the game in your Library) go to the "Local Files" tab, then select "Verify Integrity of Game Cache" it should force an update if one is available.

[image: Steam game properties window, Local files, Verify Integrity of Game Cache]

Comment: When doing this, remember to **check the betas tab to ensure you're getting the version you're after**. Some developers allow installing older versions via betas and you may be opted into those releases.