# How can I update Terraria to 1.2.4 offline?

Tags: terraria

As the title says, how can I get my game version to 1.2.4? My current game version is 1.2.0 and I'm in PC. Or am I out of luck that it only updates online? Or does it even update while online?

Comment: I'm confused. How would it be able to download the update if you were offline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is a Steam game on PC, it will be (by default) automatically updated when you are online on Steam. If you have turned automatic updates off, you can [update it manually by verifying the integrity of game cache](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/127901/).

Comment: so that means, i can't unless i go online with steam?

Comment: @ken unfortunately, yes.