# I deleted Undertale.exe by accident

Tags: undertale

I was deleting junk and By accident I deleted Undertale Thinking it was the Gaster Fight I downloaded.. How do I fix ths?

Comment: Can you redownload it from wherever you bought it?

Comment: I got it from steam

Comment: Repair the game.  All fixed.

Comment: @Frank If they knew how to do that already, would they be asking?

Comment: @MikeKellogg Based on the types of questions we get, assuming that isn't really an option.

Comment: W.D. Gaster absorbed the $00000!

Answer (score 7):

Right click on the game in your Steam library, select *Properties*, go to *Local Files* and click *Verify Integrity of Game Cache*. Steam should notice that there are some files missing and redownload them.

This advice is for the english interface, but  you should be able to find the corresponding sections in your selected language, if it's different from english.

Comment: @CrisMegaman Alright. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, if it helped or comment to let us know, if it didn't.

Comment: With images: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/127904/2259